# Type-2 Transaction Type

Tags: gas-price, eip-1559

There are a couple of tx-hashes such as [txhash1](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcc31198dd5c8c87e28c9549fc8b2cb357aa07448b471ae35fda1c739bc410d7a) and [txhash2](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x98dba01aac9534b6fc67d57a7e8984034cda51d46a19d189d7dfe95fe74f63b5) that has `Gas Price == Miner Tip` attirubute. How it that possible? Can you not pay any base fee and just pay everything to miner?

Answer (score 0):

You can send money to miners using `block.coinbase` variable.